# Customize properties in Springboot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, yaml

I need to use customize properties in springboot by retriving value from yaml file and stored it in Map.
SectionConfigurations

```
package com.tool.osoutilityapp.customconfig;


import com.tool.osoutilityapp.customconfig.model.Content;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

@Configuration
@PropertySource(value="classpath:utility-customization.yaml", ignoreResourceNotFound = true)
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "utility.customization")
public class SectionConfigurations {

    private Map<String, List<Content>> section;

    public Map<String, List<Content>> getSection() {
        return section;
    }

    public void setSection(Map<String, List<Content>> section) {
        this.section = section;
    }
```

Content

```
package com.tool.osoutilityapp.customconfig.model;

public class Content {
    private String displayName;
    private String link;

    public String getDisplayName() {
        return displayName;
    }

    public void setDisplayName(String displayName) {
        this.displayName = displayName;
    }

    public String getLink() {
        return link;
    }

    public void setLink(String link) {
        this.link = link;
    }
}
```

utility-customization.yaml

```
utility:
  customization:
    section:
      headerSection:
        - content:
            displayName: "Gerrit"
            link: "#"
        - content:
            displayName: "Gerrit1"
            link: "#"
```

UtilityController .java

```
package com.tool.osoutilityapp.controller;

import com.tool.osoutilityapp.customconfig.SectionConfigurations;
import com.tool.osoutilityapp.customconfig.model.Content;
import com.tool.osoutilityapp.exception.CustomizeException;
import com.tool.osoutilityapp.model.UIElements;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Controller
public class UtilityController {

    @Autowired
    private SectionConfigurations configurations;

    @RequestMapping("/osoUtilityCustomize")
    public String customizeHome(Model model) throws Exception {
        try{
            List<Content> data = configurations.getSection().get("headerSection");
        }catch (Exception e){
            throw new CustomizeException("Customize content from file not loaded");
        }
        return "customize-utility";
    }
}
```

**
When i try this configuration i will suppose to get value in data attribute from yaml file but its throwing exception.
**
[image]
*

Comment: Please remove @PropertySource(value="classpath:utility-customization.yaml", ignoreResourceNotFound = true) and check what results it yield.

Comment: I have tried this but still same error NullPointer Exception

Comment: Could you share the link of github repo?

Comment: https://github.com/dante1501/utility-tool

Answer (score 0):

You can refer below changes in your code:

application.yaml

```
spring:
  profiles:
    include: utility-customization
```

re-name your utility-customization.yaml to application-utility-customization.yaml

Then, in your application-utility-customization.yaml give proper syntax so that map object can be mapped like below:

```
utility:
  customization:
    section:
      headerSection:
        - displayName: 'Gerrit'
          link: '#'
        - displayName: 'Gerrit1'
          link: '#'
```

Now remove // @PropertySource(value="classpath:utility-customization.yaml") in SectionConfigurations

All of this extra work because @PropertySource annotation do not work with YAML files by default.

Hope this helps for you.

Comment: Thanks Ashutosh Mishra it worked, but can you explain me in details why previous configuration for @PropertySource is not working as per spring this annotation we can use any properties file as far as i know.

Comment: Support for yaml is not there with @PropertSource, you can use .properties files as well as there was some issue with your list layout in yaml that was also creating problem